# VBA: Move Named Sheets to New Workbook & Save

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code that works really great, but I was hoping someone could walk me through how I can move sheets that are not named **valid**, **control**, and **data**. The 3 named sheets are my constants and do not need them moved.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveSheets()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sAddress As String
Dim wbCur As Workbook
Dim wsCur As Worksheet

'-- Store path of this workbook --
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator

'-- Loop thru worksheets --
For Each wsCur In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbCur = Nothing
    '-- Add a new workbook --
    Set wbCur = Workbooks.Add
    On Error GoTo 0
    If wbCur Is Nothing Then
        '-- Report any error --
        MsgBox prompt:=Err.Description
    Else
        '-- Rename sheet 1 of new workbook --
        wbCur.Sheets(1).Name = wsCur.Name
        '-- Get range address of input data --
        sAddress = wsCur.UsedRange.Address
        '-- Copy & paste data --
        wsCur.UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbCur.Sheets(1).Range(sAddress)
        '-- Save new workbook with filename = current worksheet name --
        wbCur.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:=sPath & wsCur.Name & ".xlsx"
    End If
Next wsCur
End Sub
```

Comment: [This link](https://www.excelhowto.com/macros/move-or-copy-worksheets-vba/) should provide you with the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code:

```
Sub MoveSheets()
 Dim sPath As String, sAddress As String, wsCur As Worksheet
 Dim arrNoMoveSh, mtchSh

 arrNoMoveSh = Split("valid,control,data", ",") 'create an array of the sheets name to not be moved
 '-- Store path of this workbook --
 sPath = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator

  '-- Loop through worksheets --
 For Each wsCur In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      mtchSh = Application.match(wsCur.Name, arrNoMoveSh, 0)
      If IsError(mtchSh) Then 'no sheet names found in the array
          wsCur.Copy 'create a new workbook for the sheet to be copied!!!
          ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True, FileName:=sPath & wsCur.Name & ".xlsx"
     End If
 Next wsCur
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this, it works perfectly for what I need!